# Is '0' mandatory in DecimalFormat description?

Tags: java, decimalformat

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

The above tutorial describes **Number Format Pattern Syntax** as

```
pattern    := subpattern{;subpattern}
subpattern := {prefix}integer{.fraction}{suffix}
prefix     := '\\u0000'..'\\uFFFD' - specialCharacters
suffix     := '\\u0000'..'\\uFFFD' - specialCharacters
integer    := '#'* '0'* '0'
fraction   := '0'* '#'*
```

that makes '0' in integer part mandatory.
But the illustration in the same page uses pattern `###,###.###` which contains no `0`. Am I overlooking something or reading this completely wrong?

Comment: Hint: In the next table it says that `X* : 0 or more instances of X`. That'd be helpful.

Comment: `integer    := '#'* '0'* '0'`. 0 or more instances of `#` followed by 0 or more instances of `0` followed by mandatory `0`, which makes a single `0` mandatory isn't it?

Comment: Yes. So, it doesn't mean that every character of that pattern has to be there. It could be one/more/none(represented by `0`) of them.

Comment: `integer := '#'* '0'* ` matches exactly what you are saying. 0 or more instances of `#` followed by 0 or more instances of `0`. If so why a final `0`?

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the `0` here. Here, `0` for the pattern means that it could be any digit. So, if you write in the code say for example `"0".format(123.45)` it will give you result as `124` (Like an integer).

Comment: `0` for the pattern means that it could be any digit. yes. All I am saying is
`###,###.###` doesn't fit `integer :=#'* '0'*'0'`. Isn't it? In other words, `"###,###.###".format(123.45)` is not valid format at all.

Comment: Seems like a little mroe confusing to me now. The pattern `###,###.###` is not for integer at all. But the format that you mentioned: `"###,###.###".format(123.45)` is still valid one.

Comment: The pattern `###,###.###` is not for integer but the first 6 `#` belong to `integer` and the latter 3 `#`s belong to `fraction`. (i.e)  `integer{.fraction}` , where `integer`  is matched by `###,###` and `{.fraction}` is matched by `.###`. Since `integer`  is matched `###,###` and there is no `0` in it, it should not be valid, isn't it?

Comment: What? Again there is no must for `0` here in case of ineteger. That makes no difefrence if you use either `#` or `0` in your pattern in this case. In addition to that, you should use from `#*`, `0*` or `0` one or a combination of them.

Comment: Say for example you want to represent number `0` as a pattern. Which one would you think is correct: `#` or `0` or both?